# How to validate a block obtained with /v1/chain/get_block

Tags: blocks

Lets say that from outside the chain I call `/v1/chain/get_block` http endpoint.

I would like to be able to post that JSON back to a contract thru a context free action and validate that the block is in fact valid, or even better real.

Is that possible?

The need is actually be able to post a transaction history to a contract in order to do some actions based on calculations on it. Given the contract can't read the chain directly, I would like to post the relevant blocks to the contract from outside, and want to validate that the received information is real.